# C# - Storing a struct inside a struct of same type

Tags: c#, struct, nested

Ok,

It is not possible to store a struct instance inside a struct of the same type. So can anyone help me find a workaround please?

I need to store a vector3 inside a vector3 like this:

```
public struct Vector3{
   float x,y,z;
   Vector3 normalized;
}
```

Obviously, it creates an endless cycle as one would create a new one that creates a new one and so on...

So how would one do that? I would need my normalized to be a Vector3 since it needs to be recognized as such and cannot be any other naming.

Finally, I know this can be achieved with classes but I would not want.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't the naming change? You really can't do this in the way you are insisting.  You can use structs, but you may need to concede on the type naming/nesting.

Comment: The naming could not change because the normalized member needs to be known as a Vector3 or it becomes impossible to pass it to a method expecting a vector3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store a struct of type X inside a struct of type X.  However, you probably don't want to do this anyway, because *in general*, structs (and classes, for that matter) should only store the data they need to be complete.  Instead, you can have a function that builds and returns the 'normalized' version of the struct:

```
public struct Vector3
{
    float x,y,z;
    public Vector3 Normalized 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            ... build the normalized struct and return it ... 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of going with that one but was just wondering about the issue. For instance, I use the Unity engine and they have this kind of thing. You can also see that declaring a Vector3 vec, you end up with vec.normalized.normalized.anyOtherMember; so I was wondering how they achieve such behaviours. I guess for my case I wil go the easy way. Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly the behavior you will end up with by implementing the `Normalized` property as described.  That is, it will return a `Vector3` which will also have a `Normalized` property.  Of course, vec.Normalized should be the same as vec.Normalized.Normalized so there is no point to going deeper, but the structure will be available.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a struct is a value type. Declaring a recursive struct would create an infinitely big struct! A workaround would be to declare it as class instead. But here I would simply declare `Normalized` as a property.

```
public struct Vector3 {
    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }
    public float Z { get; private set; }

    public float Length {
        get { return (float)Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z); }
    }

    Vector3 Normalized {
        get {
            float l = Length;
            return new Vector3(X / l, Y / l, Z / l);
        }
    }
}
```